# How do I update a widget from within an event handler in Java GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, web-applications

I'm trying to create a simple Web Application with Google Web Toolkit. I have a button that I want to update another widget whenever it is clicked. The event handler for the `onClick()` event is defined in a separate file. I have tried passing a reference to the object as an argument to the method that is handling the event:

```
Button submitButton = new Button(
        "Submit",
        new ClickHandler() {
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event){
                getContentService.getContent(url.getText(),
                        new GetContentCallBack(theGwt));
            }
        }
    );
```

And here is what it looks like inside of the `GetContentCallBack.onSuccess` method (note that I've set the `gwtRef` inside of the constructor):

```
public void onSuccess(TargetContent result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.gwtRef.setProxyHTML(new HTML("<Working!>", true));
    Window.alert("I've updated the html");
}
```

I get the alert box, but the HTML widget does not update. What am I doing wrong, and how am I supposed to do this?

Comment: What  exactly this.gwtRef.setProxyHTML is doing?

Comment: How about dependency injection?

Comment: What kind of Widget is gwtRef ? Never heard of setProxyHTML...

Comment: If that onSuccess() method is from an RPC call, then 'this' will refer to the AsyncCallback class and not the class you're referring to. That's unless you've extended the AsyncCallback to include gwtRef...